# AMP: Custom font using font-face not working

Tags: font-face, amp-html

I am trying to use a custom font using font-face in my AMP pages, but the font is not rendered. The console says "Font download timed out for icons".

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'icons';
  src: url('/fonts/icos2/icomoon.ttf?126oo9') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
    font-family: 'icons';
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.icon-clock:before {
    content: "\e94e";
}
```

```html
<script async custom-element="amp-font" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-font-0.1.js"></script>

<amp-font layout="nodisplay"
  font-family="icons"
  timeout="2000"
  on-error-remove-class="icons-loading"
  on-error-add-class="icons-missing"
  on-load-remove-class="icons-loading"
  on-load-add-class="icons-loaded">
</amp-font>

<span class="icon-clock"></span>
<span class="ribbon-txt">Text</span>
```

The font is being fetched via HTTPS.

Any help will be strongly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: use full path like : example.com/fonts/icos2/icomoon.ttf?126oo9

Comment: @BachchaSingh I tried that but it didn't work.

Comment: Please share your font

Comment: @BachchaSingh https://wwwfanaticguitars.com/download/icomoon.ttf

Comment: check my answer, hope this help you

Comment: @BachchaSingh I've been a couple of hours comparing your code with mine and I didn't understand why it didn't work, because I didn't miss any of the AMP specifications. Thanks to Codepin I realized that there was an invisible character above my font-face tag that was ruining my CSS render. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PaqzbJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here is working Url](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NzPZZm)

Js on Head

```
 <script async custom-element="amp-font" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-font-0.1.js"></script>
```

Css on Head

```
<style amp-custom>
    h1 {
      color: red;
    }
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'icomoont';
    src: url(https://www.fanaticguitars.com/download/icomoon.ttf) format('truetype');
  }
    .font {font-family: 'icomoont'; color:#f00;}
    span {font-size:25px;}

    [class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
    font-family: 'icomoont';
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.icon-clock:before {
    content: "\e94e";
}
  </style>
```

HTML

```
  <span>Hello Font!</span>
  <br>
  <span class="font">Hello Font!</span>
  <br>

  <span class="icon-clock"></span>
<span class="ribbon-txt">Text</span>
```

Comment: Your codepen helped me to find a hiden special character that was ruining my font-face tag. Thanks a lot for your help. The code you posted was very helpful.